# Drupal Views ouptut - evrey next node is child of the previous

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a rather strange views output in Drupal 7.Basically, the top item is the parent of the second which is the parent of the third and so on.
A simulation of the output can be seen in [this pen](http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/rLQQKj)

I'm using Unformatted list of fields and Global: Custom text for template with the following code:

```
<div class="section-wrapper">
[field_image_main] 
<div class="section-title">[title]</div>
<div class="section-caption">[body] </div>
</div>
```

Here is a image with the view

Comment: This can happen if you forget to close an element. Check your code for missing div or anchor end tags.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by missing close tag in the [body] content.

It is very common that if you output body content from views with trim function. you should check **Field can contain HTML** in the views field configuration.

[image: views field configuration]